# I installed Ubuntu 18.04 into my laptop alongside Windows 10 (dual boot), the node version is resetting on start. Also there are some issues

Tags: dual-boot, nodejs

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 in my laptop alongside Windows 10. There are list of problems I am facing.
1. When I start my laptop it automatically boots Windows, so to get into Ubuntu, I have to go to BIOS everytime and boot Ubuntu.
2. Everytime I boot into Linux the Node version is resetting, so some of the packages are getting lost. I am using NVM to install Node, I installed v11.1.0, everytime I am restarting it is switching to v8.10.0.
3. This is happening because of the 2nd point, every time I boot, I have to install serverless globally to use it. If I shut down and come back again, serverless goes missing.
4. This happened once, I had VS Code installed, I re-booted and it was not there anymore, so I had to re-install from the browser, it was not available in Ubuntu Software.
5. I am not sure, if this is an Ubuntu Issue or an issue with my laptop, the system is freezing every once in a while.

As you can see, life is not perfect and mine is as far from perfect as it can be, please help me resolve this errors.